# Fetch data from multiple collections in mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have some collections shown like below which is holding relationships, relation between *testMaster* and *testDoc* is holding inside the *testDocMaster*

For eg:

```
testMaster {
_id: "Schema.Objectid",
name: "String" //master name
}

testDoc {
_id : Schema.ObjectId,
name: "String", //doc name
other datas
}

testDocMaster {
masterId: "_id of the testMaster table",
docId : "_id of the above testDoc"
}
```

For each master entry, we are expecting many relations,

what would be the best way to fetch the data from the testDoc table, if I have the masterId.

Comment: Relation-collections are usually an anti-pattern in MongoDB. When you have a n:m relationship, you should add an array-field to one of the documents, which holds the references to the other. I know that this sounds unintuitive when you are used to relational databases. But MongoDB is no relational database.

Comment: @Philipp that is simply not an accurate statement.  Some relationships are best represented as embedded arrays, and some are best represented as separate collections that are linked.  See my answer here for explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897305/how-would-you-model-customer-order-ordertem-product-in-nosql-database/13898439#13898439

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `testDocMaster` schema uses `ObjectId` types that `ref` the other two collections you can use Mongoose's [query population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) support to help with this:

```
TestDocMaster.findOne({ masterId: masterId})
    .populate('docId')
    .exec(function(err, testDocMaster) {
        // testDocMaster.docId is populated with the full testDoc for the
        // matching _id
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it working using this:

```
// GLOBAL ARRAYS FOR STORING COLLECTION DATA
var collectionOne = [];
var collectionTwo = [];
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/michael", function(err, db) {
    if(!err) {
      console.log("We are connected");
    }
    db.collection("collectionOne", function(err, collection) {
      collection.find().sort({order_num: 1}).toArray(function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
          throw err;
        } else {
          for (i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
            collectionOne[i] = result[i];
          }
        }
      });
      db.collection("collectionTwo", function(err, collection) {
        collection.find().sort({order_num: 1}).toArray(function(err, result) {
          if (err) {
            throw err;
          } else {
            for (i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
              collectionTwo[i] = result[i];
            }
          }
        });
      });
      // Thank you aesede!
      res.render('index.html', {
        collectionOne: collectionOne,
        collectionTwo: collectionTwo
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Now, for some reason when Node restarts, and I hit refresh, it doesn't render HTML into the front-end. However, any subsequent refresh renders the page correctly.